# Object dimensions not changing with subsurf modifier

Tags: python, subdivision-surface, dimensions

I'm writing an addon that checks anytime the active objects dimensions change and updates some properties, I'm doing this with `depsgraph_update_pre` and `depsgraph_update_post`.
As you can see in these 2 images the subsurf modifier does not have any effect on the objects dimensions, but its size in X,Y,Z clearly changes in the viewport.

[image]

[image]

I'm accessing its dimensions via `bpy.context.active_object.dimensions`
Any other modifier that effects an objects dimensions is reflected in real-time, except the subsurf modifier.

**Is there some way to get an objects true dimensions that takes the subsurf modifier into account?**

I can do it by creating a bmesh from the object and checking it's volume but this **WAY** to slow given that the check is done on every depsgraph update.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered the reason why, if anyone else stumbles across this...
Turns out this is a consequence of having GPU Subdivision turned on, turn it off and it works as expected...

Perhaps this is a bug??

[image]